# Angular2 proper way to get element/component styles

Tags: angular

There are couple of ways to get styles from an element in Angular2 :

Let say you're inside a component or a directive :

1- using nativeElement :

```
    let color = elementRef.nativeElement.style.color;
```

However , this is not recommended because you don't want to access the nativeElement directly if you're aiming to use something like a web worker in the future.

2- Using [Ruler](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6515) :

```
    this.domAdapter = new browser.BrowserDomAdapter();
    this.ruler      = new Ruler( this.domAdapter );
    this
        .ruler
        .measure( this.elementRef )
        .then( ( rect ) => {
           // Now we have access to height and width and left and top 
        } );
```

This is cool , but ruler wont give me the **color** , or any other styles , basically the ruler only gives the Rectangle (which is the Element.getBoundingClientRect() basically)  .

And also , we can't use *Renderer* to **get** element styles , it only provides methods to **set** styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible answer that I'm giving , it might not be correct but this is by far what I've got :

Possible answer :

Just looked into the Ruler class and realized it's using DomAdapter and it passes native element to get the rectangle.

```
   // This is native Angular2 source code : 
   var clntRect = this.domAdapter.getBoundingClientRect(el.nativeElement);
```

I think this means if we want to get styles, we can use domAdapter like :

```
   let color = this.domAdapter.getStyle( this.elementRef.nativeElement , 'color' )
```

As we can see , domAdapter is providing getStyles method, so that should be it hopefully !!

I'll provide more concise information as I'm going and googling and investigating.

Comment: if I set a background-position-y on a div in css and then try to get that value using method from your answer, I get empty value... Any help is appreciated